# Is it effective to repeatedly apply different compression algorithms to one file?

Tags: compression, computer-science, theory

I know that is impossible to compress a file infinitely by repeatedly applying one algorithm.

But is it possible to keep compressing a file by repeatedly applying *different* algorithms, no matter what structure of the file is?

Comment: This question may be better suited for [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Compression covers the CS theory that @MargaretBloom's answer explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
The unit we use to "weight" a file is the *byte*.
The byte is just a multiple of the more fundamental unit *bit*.

Though the word "bit" comes from "Binary digit", it's actually a measurement unit, just like *meters*, *joules*, *seconds* and so on.
A bit measure the *minimum quantity of information measurable*, just like *e* is the smallest charge.
When we say that a file has size 2 MiB we are saying that there are 2<sup>20 + 3</sup> = 8.388.608 bits of information.

Now if you want to go up an hill 20 m tall and you weight 50 Kg you need **at least** *E* = *mgh* = 50 · 9.81 · 20 = 9810 J.
No matter what you do, you need **at least** that energy or you won't get there<sup>1</sup>.
Also you can have **more** energy, 9810 J is the minimum.

The same thing apply to information. A file carries a message that need **at least** *X* bits of information to be understood unambiguously.
Most files contains more that the minimal quantity of information because files are made to be easy to process.
This is like when in English a person says "I am going out" versus "going out". Both gives the same message but one is more easy to process yet longer.

So intuitively we can remove the redundancy of a file, thereby reducing its size, until we reach the minimum *X*.
Keeping on removing bits after we reached the minimum would mean removing useful information, preventing the original file from being recovered (read: unzipped).
This is actually done with *lossy* algorithms, for example MP3, JPEG and so on.

This intuition that strings cannot be infinitely compressed is easily proven.
We follow the approach of Chapter 6.4 of *Introduction to Theory of Computation* by Sipser.

We assign a weight to a string *s* in this way: we consider all the algorithms *A* that when processing a, new, string *Ma* output *s*.
We encode each *A* and *Ma* as a string and we set *K(s)* as the length of the *shortest* of such string.
*K(s)* is called the *minimal descriptor* of *s* and represent the smallest information needed to generate *s*.

If *K(s)* is less than the length *s* than *s* is said *compressible*.
We now show that there are *non-compressible* strings.

Suppose *s* has length *n*. There are 2<sup>n</sup> possible such strings.
If *s* is compressible then it has a minimal descriptor of length at most *n-1*.
There are 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2<sup>n-1</sup> = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 such descriptors.
Since each descriptor defines a string uniquely and there are less descriptors than strings of length *n*, some string of length *n* is uncompressible.
By the arbitrarily of  *n* uncompressible strings of any length exists.

So in short, if we keep compressing we eventually reach an uncompressible file.
In practice a good compression algorithm should remove most of the redundancy at the first step without adding a significant amount of information.
That's why zipping a jpeg, an already compressed format, doesn't produce the same result as zipping a text file. 
Also this explain why encrypted files, that appear to be random, so without any redundancy, cannot be compressed very well.

---

<sup>1</sup> We deal only with simple Newtonian physic here.

Comment: To be fair, the OP is allowing the use of multiple different algorithms. In that case, the proof above from ITC of a limit to compressibility doesn't apply: because now every descriptor may define _more than one_ string, depending on what algorithm is used. In effect, the descriptor used is now a tuple (descriptor, algorithm), and an arbitrary amount of information can be stashed away in the selection of the algorithm. For example, see my answer for a family of simple algorithms that can be repeatedly selected and applied to compress _any_ file.

Comment: ... of course, there is the _little problem_ of remembering which algorithm was used, but if the OP has a very good memory perhaps it isn't a problem :)

Comment: @BeeOnRope A descriptor contains the encoding of an algorithm *A*, actually a TM. Applying different algorithms in succession is still an algorithm, so we need at most one descriptor. That proof is universally valid, that's the power of the computational theory. :)

Comment: Sure, but then you are proving something different than what the OP asked and so it's not directly applicable to the OP's question! The OP is explicitly asking about a "small file", i.e., the descriptor they are interested in is the output string, separate from the TM that decodes it. They are not including the size of the compressor in their file size (as most people don't - if I say "Hey I'm sending you a 20k gzipped file, the file itself is going to be 20k, and won't include the size of the gzip binary on your system).

Comment: @BeeOnRope You still need the TM. Now if you use *gzip* as the TM you can use it on many different files, if you use a specific program, like the sequence of compressor it only works on a single file. So you have to send a new sequence for each file. Anyway sorry for missing the tongue-in-cheek in my comment below :)

Comment: Yeah, carefully defining the problem _very important_ when discussing this stuff - failure could [cost you real money](http://patrickcraig.co.uk/other/compression.php). The OP phrased his question in such a way that what they want _is possible_, probably just without the actual result they may want (although I'd only be guessing if I said they want to reduce storage requirements - for all I know this is an interview question and a tricky answer is exactly what they're looking for).

Comment: @BeeOnRope I realise only now that the OP asked two different questions: one in the title and one in the body. I answered the one in the title while you answered the one on the body. I see what you meant now.

Comment: Good point, I never noticed the title didn't really cover the idea of repeated application an algorithm - but I think that's what they were getting at based on the body. It seems this is the classic "can we repeatedly apply a compression algorithm?" question - with the new twist that you can choose a different algorithm at least step.

Comment: Bonus question - can you do what I did in my answer with a family of only two algorithms, rather than four? Nothing immediately obvious jumped out at me. Perhaps there is a proof out there that you can't do it without being able to store fractional bits.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can** - to the point where the file eventually becomes empty - but of course you'd just be moving the entropy from the file itself into the choice of compression algorithm (and into the record of which compression algorithm was chosen).

For example, let me define the following compressor, which looks at the first two bits in the file, and encodes those bits and then outputs the remainder of the file unchanged.

> Algorithm `compress00`:
>
> If the first two bits in the file are `00`, replace those two bits
>   with a single 0 bit - in this case, the file is 1 bit shorter.
>   Otherwise, prepend a 1 to the file - in this case, the file is 1 bit
>   longer.

This algorithm is easily invertible (i.e., the output can be unambiguously decompressed) and it either shortens or lengthens the file by 1 bit.  Imagine a family of 4 compressors: `compress00, compress01, compress10, compress11`, which all have the same behavior except that, for example, `compress01` shortens the file if it starts with `01` and lengthens it otherwise, and so on for the other compressors.

Note now that *every* file of at least two bits either starts with 00, 01, 10, or 11 - so at *every* stage in your process of repeated compression you can choose the algorithm that compresses the file by 1 bit. Repeated application of this process will reduce the file down to a single bit (and you can define some additional behavior for 1 bit files to get down to 0 bits).

Of course, a *very minor* downside of this method is that to effectively decompress the you need to remember which compressors you chose at each step.

Comment: Try to estimate the entropy needed to remember the sequence of compressors, you'll find a nice surprise :) That's why Sipser explicitly include the algorithm in the descriptor of a string. Seriously, that **not** a "minor" downside at all!

Comment: @MargaretBloom - perhaps, but you are perhaps missing an implied tongue-in-cheek or two. Still, it's a valid answer to the explicit phrasing of the OP's question! Furthermore, you can argue that the entropy needed to remember the sequence of compressors can be stored in some side-band location that might not be part of the "size" as defined in the problem, e.g., in filename extensions.

Comment: This is another flavour of the 5000$ compression challenge from Usenet where a clever person noticed that the wording had a loophole, that filename metadata wasn't counted. (https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2ybd6i/the_5000_compression_challenge/ has some history of why the challenge existed at all: apparently comp.compression on Usenet had a lot of nonsense claims, so this was similar in concept to James Randi's 1 M$ prize for verified proof of the supernatural.)

Answer (score 0):

You can but it does not make any difference. Most of the compression algorithms operate based on reducing the redundancy, however some are more efficient and therefore slower.

Now when you apply the first algorithm it reduces those redundancies, so applying the second does not make much difference.

Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) for more info.